# How do I access a pointer from within a nested class?

Tags: c++

This class's purpose is to emulate the functions of a Binary Search Tree. In the below code, I am trying to adapt it from a struct and a bunch of functions, into a wrapper class, called BST. One thing I am not sure of however, is how to access 'root' from within the node struct. Root is currently declared within the BST class.

```
class bst
{
public:
struct Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;


    Node* FindMin(Node* root)
    {
        while(root->left != NULL) root = root->left;
        return root;
    }

    Node* Insert(Node *root,int data)
    {
        if(root == NULL) {
            root = new Node();
            root->data = data;
            root->left = root->right = NULL;

            //Update Height & Size
            bstHeight = 0;
            bstSize = 0;
        }
        else if(data <= root->data)
            root->left = Insert(root->left,data);
        else
            root->right = Insert(root->right,data);
        return root;

    }

    Node* Delete(struct Node *root, int data)
    {
        if(root == NULL) return root;
        else if(data < root->data) root->left = Delete(root->left,data);
        else if (data > root->data) root->right = Delete(root->right,data);
        //Value found
        else {
            // Case 1:  No child
            if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
            {
                delete root;
                root = NULL;

                //Update Height & Size
                bstHeight = 0;
                bstSize = 0;
            }
            //Case 2: One child
            else if(root->left == NULL)
            {
                struct Node *temp = root;
                root = root->right;
                delete temp;

                //Update Height & Size
                bstHeight = 0;
                bstSize = 0;
            }
            else if(root->right == NULL)
            {
                struct Node *temp = root;
                root = root->left;
                delete temp;

                //Update Height & Size
                bstHeight = 0;
                bstSize = 0;
            }
            // case 3: 2 children
            else
            {
                struct Node *temp = FindMin(root->right);
                root->data = temp->data;
                root->right = Delete(root->right,temp->data);

                //Update Height & Size
                bstHeight = 0;
                bstSize = 0;
            }
        }
        return root;
    }

    //# of Nodes in tree
    void size(Node *root)
    {
        //Check if end
        if(root == NULL) return;
        //Not end
        else
        {
            bstSize = bstSize + 1;
            size(root->left);       //Visit left subtree
            size(root->right);      // Visit right subtree

        }
    }

    void height(Node *root, int temp)
    {
        //Check if end
        if(root == NULL)
        {
            if(temp > bstHeight)
            {
                bstHeight = temp;
            }

            return;
        }

        //Not end
        else
        {
            temp = temp + 1;
            height(root->left, temp);       //Visit left subtree
            height(root->right, temp);      // Visit right subtree

        }
    }

    //Function to visit nodes in Inorder
    void show()
    {
        if(root == NULL) return;

        show(root->left);       //Visit left subtree
        printf("%d ",root->data);  //Print data
        show(root->right);      // Visit right subtree
    }

    void check(Node *root)
    {
        //End of a 'branch'
        if(root == NULL) return;

        int value = 0;
        value = root->data;

        //Checking left subtree
        if(value < root->left->data)
        {
            //Tree is NOT valid
            valid = 0;
        }

        //Checking right subtree
        if(value > root->right->data)
        {
            //Tree is NOT valid
            valid = 0;
        }

        check(root->left);       //Visit left subtree
        printf("%d ",root->data);  //Print data
        //check(root->right);      // Visit right subtree
    }

};
Node* root = NULL;
};
```

Specifically, in the show function. It's not as simple as putting it into Node with the rest of the functions, as root needs to be unique, and new Node is called at least once. Show will not compile in the current state, and I'm not sure where to proceed from here.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. A nested class is not a formal member of its parent class. It's just a type definition that's a part of the class's namespace. There is no linked instance of a parent class that each instance of the nested class automatically is a part of. So, to access something from the parent, the nested class must have a pointer, or a reference, somewhere, to an instance of its parent class, and just access it via the pointer or reference. Note that this is somewhat different than Java. If you're coming from a Java background, try to forget everything you know. C++ is different.

Answer (score 0):

Though the comment says everything, let me give an additional hint:

When you want to keep your code as similar as possible to what you have now, try to add a constructor to the Node class that expects a pointer or reference (preferable) to the root and check, that each time you create a Node, you give the root to the constructor.

By the way, it might even be a better approach to look at some simple Node-based data structure implementations in C++, for example in the thread

[Simple linked list in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141477/simple-linked-list-in-c)